# Centering a long line that spills over the margins.

Tags: margins, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to TeX a fairly long line of text:

```
\exists C\forall f(f\in C\Leftrightarrow f\in\ms{F}\wedge (\forall x\forall y)((x\in\dom f\wedge y\in\dom f\Rightarrow x=y)\wedge(\forall z)(z\in\dom f\Rightarrow \op{z}{z}\in f))).
```

The problem is, when I build, the line spills a little bit into the right margin. I don't mind terribly much, as the whole line fits, but is it possible to center the line so that is spills equally over in the left and right margins? I don't really want to split this formula among two lines.

If it's helpful, my preamble is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\input{other/packages.tex}
\input{other/theoremdef.tex}
```

where packages.tex is

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[top=1.3in, bottom=1.3in, left=1.3in, right=1.3in]{geometry}

% header and footer
\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xy}
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
```

And theoremdef.tex is:

```
\newtheorem{exercise}{\bf Exercise}
\newcommand{\dom}{\text{dom}\ }
\newcommand{\ran}{\text{ran}\ }
\newcommand{\fld}{\text{fld}\ }
\newcommand{\op}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\ot}[3]{\langle #1,#2,#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\ms}[1]{\mathscr{#1}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize long line you, possibly, may want to do that like this:

```
\newbox\formBox

\def\forMULA#1{%
  \setbox\formBox=\hbox{#1}%
    \centerline{%
      \ifdim\wd\formBox>\linewidth%
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{#1}%
      \else%
        #1%
      \fi}}

\forMULA{$\exists C\forall f(f\in C\Leftrightarrow f\in\ms{F}\wedge (\forall x\forall y)((x\in\dom f\wedge y\in\dom f\Rightarrow x=y)\wedge(\forall z)(z\in\dom f\Rightarrow \op{z}{z}\in f))).$}
```

This inserts (for testing purpose) your formula into a box and tests if this box's dimension exceeds `\linewidth`. If so, scales it to fit. If not, inserts unscaled.

`\centerline` is used to prevent `\parindent` (you may want to use `\noindent` instead --- if you don't need the content to be centered).

You also need to `\usepackage{graphicx}` --- to have `\resizebox` available.

But if you want to center long line (to fly out over margins equally) you may use the following:

```
\newbox\formBox
\newskip\formSkip

\def\forMULAE#1{%
  \setbox\formBox=\hbox{#1}%
  \centerline{%
  \ifdim\wd\formBox>\linewidth%
    \setlength{\formSkip}{{\wd\formBox - \linewidth}/2}%
    \begingroup\leftskip=-\formSkip #1\endgroup%
  \else%
    #1% 
  \fi}}
```

This requires to `\usepackage{calc}` also.

Comment: Thanks brownian, I just got around to putting this in, and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

try this, if it is not too small:
`\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{$ ...formula ...}`

Answer (score 1):

With the `adjustbox` package you can simply write:

```
\adjustbox{center}{\exists C\forall f(f\in C\Leftrightarrow f\in\ms{F}\wedge (\forall x\forall y)((x\in\dom f\wedge y\in\dom f\Rightarrow x=y)\wedge(\forall z)(z\in\dom f\Rightarrow \op{z}{z}\in f))).}
```

to center it on the normal text area without rescaling.

If you want to rescale it to fit the line width use either `width=\linewidth` or better `max width=\linewidth` (which only scales it when the width is larger then the given value). These options should be before `center`, e.g. `\adjustbox{max width=\linewidth,center}{...}`.

Note that `\adjustbox` reads its content as box, so there can also be verbatim or other special content in it. There is also the `adjustbox` environment if you prefer that one.